# Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 Drivers Missing Would Not Install?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, drivers, bluetooth

I am building my dev machine with WS2008R2SP1. I consider Windows Server as the best development environment for C# since I tend to focus on server-centric (integration) applications. The desktop flavor of Windows (7) doesn't play nicely with things like Commerce Server or BizTalk... so I to like stick to the environment I develop for. Previously I used to develop inside of VM's but I've found that it is super inefficient and tends to take a toll on the laptops. (I've gone through two of them in 6 months).

Problem is that I multiple devices that do not want to be recognized by Windows:

```
My machine is Dell Precision M4500:
Intel Core i7-Q740, 
1TB HDD, 
8GB RAM, 
Dell re-branded Broadcom DW1501 802x11n Half-Mini Card, 
Dell re-branded Broadcom DW375 Bluetooh Module, 
Intel 82577LM Gigabit Network connection
NVidia Quadro FX1800 Graphics
```

The devices in question are the Dell rebranded broadcom network and bluetooth adapters:

`Broadcom USH:
USB\VID_0A5C&PID_5800&REV_0101&MI_00
USB\VID_0A5C&PID_5800&MI_00`

`DW375 Bluetooth Module
USB\VID_413C&PID_8187&REV_0517
USB\VID_413C&PID_8187`

When I ran the broadcom installers I get "Operating System not supported" which I think is a big oversight on Broadcom's part. Why check for system version string? UGHGHGH

Moreover if I try to manually force the driver in windows... I get an error:

`Driver Management concluded the process to install driver FileRepository\btwampsecfl.inf_amd64_neutral_d8fc2b85d035ed47\btwampsecfl.inf for Device Instance ID USB\VID_0A5C&PID_5800&MI_00\7&66DE6C9&0&0000 with the following status: 0xe0000217.`

'- or -

`Driver Management concluded the process to install driver FileRepository\btwampfl.inf_amd64_neutral_d4c4acf036c61299\btwampfl.inf for Device Instance ID USB\VID_413C&PID_8187\90004EEEF5A6 with the following status: 0xe0000217.`

I googled the `0xe0000217` error code and it says `Bad service install section` in the driver inf file...

Any ideas on how to fix this?

I also tried the post by `BetaIQ` on [MSDN Forum](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverPN/thread/fd2b1573-9836-4ddb-90b6-e6c08b31a2c8), unfortunately the links to the driver package included in the post were dead :(

PS. On a side note I also do mobile development for Android, iOS, and Windows Phone, and BB. Having the bluetooth is quite useful with mobile devices.

Comment: Have you tried Dell's drivers?

Comment: Did you try the windows 7 x64 drivers?  many times those seem to work for us.  since there are both 32 and 64 bit versions of windows 7, this might be an oversight.

Comment: The windows 7x64 drivers throw an Exception stating that the drivers are not "Licensed" for this version of Windows. :(

Comment: Bluetooth is not really supported on Windows Server operating systems. If you absolutely need it, stick with a desktop OS.

Answer (score 1):

For some installers, simply running it in compatibility mode for the desired operating system is enough to trick it into working.

Comment: I tried this. Doesn't work.